# Trouble with findViewByIdOrRaise in AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

Trying to use MonkeyRunner to perform some testing and want to use AndroidViewClient to work with EditText widgets.

I believe I am using AndroidViewClient correctly (relevant stuff below), `findViewByIdOrRaise()` is always throwing an error.  I've tried every variant of specifying an ID that came to mind.

Here is a snippet from my activity's XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/someText"
    ... >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<!-- Yes, that is the actual id of my EditText -->
```

In my MonkeyRunner script I have the following:

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExity(serialNo=myDeviceId)
vc = ViewClient(device=device, serialno=serialno)
device.installPackage(apkPath)
device.startActivity(component='com.app.name/com.app.name.ActivityName')
editTextId = 'id/someText'
try:
    someText = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(editTextId)
    someText.touch()
    someText.type('Derp derp derp')
except ViewNotFoundException, e:
    # The comma above is because Jython 2.5.3 does not support the AS keyword
    print ' [*] %s' % (e)
```

Of course, my code is doing a little more (but not much) than what is shown.  I stripped out everything that didn't seem relevant. I will gladly put it all up there, but didn't want to start off with code vomited all up in here.

I've looked at everything I could find on the topic:

- [AndroidViewClient / AndroidViewClient / examples / email-send.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/email-send.py)
- [monkeyrunner: interacting with the Views](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html)
- [How to enter text in text field using monkeyrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931728/how-to-enter-text-in-text-field-using-monkeyrunner)
- [How to enter values to a text field using monkeyrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741355/how-to-enter-values-to-a-text-field-using-monkeyrunner)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of ViewClient gives a unique id to each view in the app. The id format is i/no_id/number. You could use a script called dump.py to see the current views. It is located in the examples folder in ViewClient.

Comment: Great, with that I was able to figure it out.  Wrote my own methods to find unique ids. For reference, here is the script you mentioned: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/dump.py